# How to redirect to an external url with react-bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

How to redirect to social media links from my navbar social icons?

I want to redirect to an Instagram page when clicking on Instagram icon and so on.

Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Nav } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Navbar } from "react-bootstrap";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import {
  faInstagram,
  faFacebook,
  faTwitter,
} from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons";

import "./Footer.css";

const Footer = () => {
  return (
    <Navbar className="main-footer justify-content-center" fixed="bottom">
      <Nav>
        <Nav.Link href="#">About us</Nav.Link>
        <Nav.Link href="#">Contact us</Nav.Link>
        <Nav.Link href="#">Join us</Nav.Link>
      </Nav>
      <Nav className="position-absolute end-0">

        **<Nav.Link to="www.instagram.com" exact>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faInstagram} />
        </Nav.Link>
        <Nav.Link href="">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFacebook} />
        </Nav.Link>
        <Nav.Link href="">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTwitter} />
        </Nav.Link>**
      </Nav>
    </Navbar>
  );
};

export default Footer;
```

Answer (score 0):

try to do something like this

```
<Link to={{ pathname: "https://example.zendesk.com/" }} target="_blank" />
```

also if you want to redirect to out of you website there is no need to use Link just use a tag and redirect user like bellow

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://google.com">Google</a>
```

Comment: What is the import for "Link" (first example)? Thanks!